# ¿Dónde puedo ver las razones de cerrar una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Me encuentro con [una pregunta de un nuevo usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/110571) que parecía necesitar ser cerrado porque llama más a la opinión de las personas que a una respuesta objetiva. Yo voto para cerrar. Quería explicar mi elección al tipo que hace la pregunta. Sin embargo, no encontré dónde encontrar los motivos detallados que podrían desencadenar el cierre de una pregunta, ya que estaba en el tablero de cierre, así que me retracté para volver a hacer el proceso y utilizar el motivo en mi comentario. Sin embargo, esto solo déjame el siguiente mensaje:

> Estoy reportando esta pregunta como :
>
> ...
>
> debería ser cerrada... Esta pregunta es confusa, incompleta, excesivamente amplia, principalmente basada en opiniones o no se trata de Stack Overflow en español como se describe en el centro de ayuda. Es poco probable que pueda ser corregida a través de la edición.
>
> Has retractado tu reporte de "cierre recomendado"

Entonces, si no podemos cancelar nuestra retractación, lo cual es una pena, ¿dónde podemos encontrar las razones para cerrar las preguntas?

Comment: Los motivos de cierre los puedes ver en el diálogo mostrado después de hacer clic en "cerrar" de cualquier pregunta donde no te hayas retractado.

Comment: Entonces, una vez elegido, ya es demasiado tarde para volver a recoger elementos para comentar.

Comment: Sobre la misma pregunta que se ha votado para cerrar y luego retractado el voto uno mismo no puede consultar todos los motivos de cierre mientras esté en marcha la revisión en curso. Una vez que ésta termine se podrá consultarlos de nuevo y votar si así se considera apropiado.

Comment: @Rubén Creo que marine no ve los motivos de cierre finales, si no los reportes que puede elevar para las colas de revision, ya que no cuenta con reputacion suficiente para cerrar.

Comment: Si quieres ver los motivos, abre otra pregunta en la que no hayas votado para cerrar. Como bien indica @Rubén, una vez votaste en un caso, ya no puedes verlos otra vez.

Comment: Alternativamente existe la posibilidad de mejorar la pregunta en vez de cerrarla, que es lo que he intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al dar clic en la opción `cerrar`, puedes ver un dialogo que te presenta opciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ya votaste, des afortunadamente no se mostrará nuevamente el diálogo, por lo que te sugiero que para que tengas un mejor criterio sobre que preguntas marcar como cerrar o no, también te recomiendo leer:

**[¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

**Marine1, muchas gracias por tu apoyo a esta tarea para el bien de la comunidad, saludos!**